# How to make UILabel resize it's dimensions correctly when the view width changes?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uilabel

I have a UILabel configured to automatically size for multi-lines depending on text length.  The label is in a dynamically sizing UITableViewCell with constraints on all size.

The code moves UILabel origin to the right, thereby shrinking the UILabel width.

The label correctly resizes and wraps the text.  In the process of positioning the origin back to it's original location, the height of the UILabel expands for 3 lines.  But only 2 lines of text are required.

The reason the height expands to 3 lines is that in the process of returning the origin back to the original point with view animation, The text expands to 3 lines and reduces back to 2.

Is there a call or setting to make that will have the cell resize correctly? Or 2 is there a way to keep the cell from resizing when he origin changes.  In particular. Is it possible to momentarily disable the UILabel multi-line option as the width shrinks and expands?

Here are screenshots showing the behavior.

Figure (1) Position of label in the UITableViewCell before changing its origin.

[image: Before label origin Move]

Figure (2) Origin of UILabel moves to the right and reduces the width of the label. Notice the second row has 2 lines and the label border tightly hugs the text.

[image: Moved label origin right]

Figure (3) Origin returns the position of the first image. Notice the UIlabel of the second row loosely hugs the text and does not return to it's original height.

[image: Return origin to the first position]

```
    @IBAction func editTable(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if isEditingDynamic  {
        let animate = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.4, curve: .easeIn) {
            for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells as! [CellResize] {
                cell.lblDescription.frame.origin.x = 16
            }
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        animate.addCompletion(){
            (position:UIViewAnimatingPosition) in
            for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells as! [CellResize] {
                cell.leadingContraint.constant = 0
            }
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        animate.startAnimation()
        isEditingDynamic = false
    } else {
        let animate = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.4, curve: .easeIn) {
            for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells as! [CellResize] {
                cell.lblDescription.frame.origin.x = 60
            }
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        animate.addCompletion(){
            (position:UIViewAnimatingPosition) in
            for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells as! [CellResize] {
                cell.leadingContraint.constant = 54
            }
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        animate.startAnimation()
        isEditingDynamic = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to post some codes of how your table view cells and controller is set up? Typically, what I will do is I will create a single line UILabel and place it inside the cell's content view, constraining it `Top`, `Left`, `Trailing` & `Leading` with a `height constraint >= current` & `numberOfLines = 0`.

Then, in the `tableview cell`, I will set its `estimatedHeight to be 100` and `heightForRow to be UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

In this case, `TableView` will automatically handle the height of the cell based on the label's contents.

Comment: Yes, I've configured the cell to be dynamic with all the attributes as you describe except the height one.  There is no height constraint since the 4 sides are all set.  The problem is in the animation of the resize.  I can see as the label resizes to the original size, the UILabel wraps the text from 2 lines to 3 lines and then back to 2 before it finishes.  Once the label is set to 3 lines, it does not readjust the height to 2 lines until the label origin is made smaller again.